# How to publish 3 tier architecture application in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Hi i have 3 tier architecture solution that has 3 projects, i want publish the solution as 1 app. when i try publish i get the option of publishing one project, the app won't work without the other projects.

[image]

option to publish one project

[image]

After publishing the application i get the following error, the file `Students.accdb` is the `Orange_Student_DAL` project.

[image]

Comment: If all of the layers will be working on the same set of hardware, you need to publish your presentation layer. Probably you are referencing the business layer from presentation layer and data layer from business layer. Your business layer probably have the .dll files for other projects.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi i get `could not find file` error but the file is in the `Orange_Student_DAL` project, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer, right click on the top level solution. Select the "Project Dependencies" option. A window with two tabs, "Project Dependencies" and "Build Order". You probably need to set PL to depend on BLL, and BLL to depend on DAL. You can also change the build order if necessary.